# Split line at point doesn't split lines less than 30 meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, file-geodatabase, splitting

I have a bunch of lines in line layer that should be split at midpoint.
I tried to use both **Feature Vertices to Points** and **Feature to Point** to get a new layer with point at the middle of lines. I even used topology check to fit points and lines at coordinate grid.

[image]

Eventually lines that have a length more than 25-30 meters are split while others are not! And I need to split all the lines in layer.

[image]

**On a picture above you can see that two last lines at right are not split.**

I also tried to use different projections but it didn't help.
Is there any solution or this is a bug of a tool whcih cannot split lines with length that is less than 30 meters?

***UPDATE***

Found out that export lines to shapefile gives positive result, i.e. lines can be split in that way.
But I try to use only GDB file format so that and the final result of this operation will be presented in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Is your update saying that this is a problem in a file geodatabase feature class but works fine for a shapefile?

Comment: @PolyGeo right. I need this tool wotking in GDB, not with shapefiles

Comment: What is the precise procedure that you are using to try and split these lines at their midpoint?

Comment: what is your precision for storing the gdb feature class ?

Comment: @PolyGeo I make "bridges" that have to be split at midpoint and then according to the position of output lines, their direction and start/mid points I give specific attributes to new lines, i.e. "begin line" and "end line". This procedure stores in a Model, which saves time instead of doing it manually

Comment: I tried Split Polylines tool of the XTools Pro extension and it succesfully splitted polyline of 15 meters into two equal lines. Input polyline and result are both stored in GDB. Standard tool Feature Vertices to Points also produced correct middle point...

Comment: @Maxim I have to share a complete script to other users that probably haven't this extension

Comment: @PavelPereverzev, But I tried standard tool Feature Vertices to Points (Point Type = MID) and it succesfully created middle point of 15 meters line. Can you give sample data so I can test it?

Comment: @Maxim I forgot to say in a comment below that my Feature Vertices to Points is also works fine, but when it comes to splitting the line, Split lines by points works as I noted in question

Comment: @PavelPereverzev Split Line at Point also works fine for me... You can try to set Search Radius parameter or set XY tolerance in the tool's Environment Settings.